# Pandas: Groupby multiple columns, finding the max value and keep other columns in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max, pandas-groupby

I am looking to group multiple columns in a dataframe, keep only the max Value, and keeping the corresponding date column

Below is how the dataframe looks like:

| Index | Site | Device Type | Value | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | A | 10 | 2021-02-02 01:30:00 |
| 1 | AAA | A | 5 | 2021-02-02 01:35:00 |
| 2 | AAA | B | 2 | 2021-02-02 01:40:00 |
| 3 | BBB | C | 3 | 2021-02-02 02:00:00 |
| 4 | BBB | C | 11 | 2021-02-02 02:05:00 |
| 5 | BBB | C | 20 | 2021-02-02 02:10:00 |
| 6 | BBB | D | 30 | 2021-02-02 04:00:00 |

I am trying to get the following output:

| Index | Site | Device Type | Value | Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | AAA | A | 10 | 2021-02-02 01:30:00 |
| 1 | AAA | B | 2 | 2021-02-02 01:40:00 |
| 2 | BBB | C | 20 | 2021-02-02 02:10:00 |
| 3 | BBB | D | 30 | 2021-02-02 04:00:00 |

When I try the following groupby, the Time column drops:
`df_max = df.groupby(['Site','Device Type'],as_index=False)['Value'].max()`

I am looking to Keep the Time value corresponding to the maximum value found.

Thank you

Answer (score 11):

You are very close. try using `idxmax` and show rows at that location:

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['Site','Device Type'])['Value'].idxmax()].reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    Index   Site    Device Type Value   Time
0   0       AAA     A           10      2021-02-02 01:30:00
1   2       AAA     B           2       2021-02-02 01:40:00
2   5       BBB     C           20      2021-02-02 02:10:00
3   6       BBB     D           30      2021-02-02 04:00:00
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! this works perfectly :) you made my day!